# How can we check that javaFx application is already running?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way that we can check if our javaFx application is already running. If yes then show the existing instance of application otherwise launch a new instance.

Comment: how you run it?do you run it from another application[java or another ] ?

Comment: Some kind of locking using file/ports will be good enough.  See some at https://community.oracle.com/thread/2393167?tstart=0

Answer (score -2):

Well I am sure there is probably a better solution out there, but when I encountered the issue I just made a boolean that would be changed once the start method was ran having it false as default.

Comment: You are aware that multiple instances of the JVM can be started, which means 2 **different variables** would be in memory one per JVM.