# How to close the javax application if the same instance is already running?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

I am running my java application by jar file. Now a certain need forces me to check other instance of same application running or not on same Machine. For e.g i must restrict to run only one instance of application to make run, close other application (if running on other tab on terminal). I have searched similar threats from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688537/how-can-we-check-that-javafx-application-is-already-running), but actually unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to create a lock-file when you start your application. When you start a second instance it can check for the existence of such a file and terminate if one is found. When you close the first instance it has to delete this file of course before it finally terminates.